# How to JOIN, including row with NULL data

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I my question gives this way *Return customers and their orders, including customers who placed no orders.*

I have written such code

```
SELECT A.custid, A.companyname, 
       B.orderid, B.orderdate

FROM Sales.Customers as A
  JOIN sales.orders as B
   ON A.custid=B.custid;
```

It works almost right, except one point, it doest return such rows, where `orderid` and `orderdate` equal `NULL`

```
custid     companyname         orderid   orderdate
------     -------------       ------    ---------
57         Customer WVAXS      NULL       NULL
```

In addition, I cant understand why my code doesn`t work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a left join for this:

```
SELECT A.custid, A.companyname, 
       B.orderid, B.orderdate

FROM Sales.Customers as A
  LEFT JOIN sales.orders as B
   ON A.custid=B.custid;
```

A left join includes all rows from the Customers table and only the ones in the orders table where a match occurs -- thus you can have null for B's columns.