# SQL JOIN but include nulls

Tags: mysql

If I have 15 rows in one table and i join another table to it, can i still output all 15 even if i want to join where the value could be null? Basically can you JOIN + include nulls from the result of the join. For example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

After join only 3 have the join parameter

```
2
4
5
```

How can i display everything?

I tried the following:

```
"SELECT * 
        FROM `ultrait_wpl_properties` 
        JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
        ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
        ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id"
```

---

This part outputs duplicate IDs?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `ultrait_wpl_properties` 
        LEFT JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
        ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
        ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // Connect and run query

$dom = new DOMDocument(); // New DOM

$root = $dom->createElement('root'); // Create parent or root node
$dom->appendChild($root); // Append the root tag to the DOM

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $node = $textContent = null; // $node will equal $textContent which is null
    $property = $dom->createElement('property'); // Create containing node

    foreach($r as $column_name => $val) { // Loop through key value pairs
        // so loop all the values on each row
```

Comment: You want to use what is called an `outer join`. Depending on which of the tables has your null data, you would use either `left join` or `right join`.

Comment: You need left/right join and not inner join. Which table has null value in your query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to JOIN, including row with NULL data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106424/how-to-join-including-row-with-null-data)

Comment: the left table, so left join?

Comment: @JesseOrange Why not suck it and see. You've got a 50 percent chance of being right.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
"SELECT * 
    FROM `ultrait_wpl_properties` 
    LEFT JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
    ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
    ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id"
```

OR:

```
"SELECT * 
    FROM `ultrait_wpl_properties` 
    RIGHT JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
    ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
    ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id"
```

shree.pat18 is correct it either depends on your situation to use INNER, RIGHT OR LEFT JOIN

Comment: Is there any reason the outputted IDs would be repeated? ID is the first column in the left table

Comment: It won't be repeated. But it will give you the null value if the records on your first record does not match with the second record. Please refer to this http://i.imgur.com/hhRDO4d.png

Comment: I have a PHP script that loops through the database but for some reason it outputs the same ids twice but with different content?

Comment: In that case I think you need to post your PHP script with your SQL Statements.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try `left join`

```
SELECT * 
        FROM `ultrait_wpl_properties` 
        LEFT JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types 
        ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id
        ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id
```